# How to remove a Gapp after installing it?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, uninstallation, cyanogenmod, samsung-apps

I just flashed the CM 11 nightly build on my S2. I have also installed the Gapps from the source provided by CM website. Now it has brought me many unwanted apps to my phone. I would like to remove apps like Hangouts, Gmail, Play Books. Kindly suggest me some methods....

Thanks a ton in advance.

KS.Rajkumar

Answer (score 1):

When you flash `Gapps.zip` (or really any zip in recovery mode), the applications in it are usually written to the `/system` partition on the device.

The difficulty is that the system partition is only mounted as 'writable' when installing the Gapps zip. After that, it's mounted as 'read-only', making it impossible to delete things on it.

You basically have two options for deleting unwanted system applications:

1. Start over: Reflash your ROM, then flash a modified version of the Gapps zip that has only the APKs you require.

   You can remove apps from the Gapps zip simply by unzipping it, deleting the APKs you do not want, then zipping it up again.
2. Acquire root access, and remount the system partition as writable. You'll need the android command line tools installed to do this, but it sounds like you already have.

   To mount the system partition as writable, do the following:

   ```
   adb shell
   su 
   mount -o remount,rw /system
   ```

   > Note: /system is only writable until the device is rebooted.

   You then need to delete the unwanted APKs from `/system/app`. Reboot, and you should see the offending apps gone from your launcher.

Please bear in mind, however, that some Google apps depend on each other, and may not work properly if you delete those that they depend on. I think you'll generally be ok if you only delete 'named' applications (e.g. Hangouts.apk). Others such as GoogleHome.apk are required by others.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is with `Titanium Backup` application.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you can't remove any of them, you can at least *disable* some of them going to "Apps" in "Settings".

You won't free space in your device, but at least they will stop consuming RAM and phoning home.